# Protocol Buffers Invalid embedded descriptor problem

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I'm having some problems at runtime with some of my generated protocol buffer classes.

My project layout is as follows:

```
module/
  protobuf-api/
    proto/
      com/foo/api/Service.proto
      com/foo/shared/Shared.proto
      org/bar/api/Message1.proto
      org/bar/api/Message2.proto
```

The Service.proto file depends on Shared.proto and some of the Message*.proto files. From the protobuf-api directory, I run the following command to compile:
`find . -name *.proto -exec protoc --java_out=java -I=proto {} \;`

When I attempt to run my Service, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.linkedin.history.api.protobuf.HistoryServiceProtos$HistoryServiceQuery.(HistoryServiceProtos.java:544)
    at com.linkedin.history.api.serializer.HistoryServiceSerializer.serialize(HistoryServiceSerializer.java:47)
     at test.history.serializer.TestSerializer.testHistoryServiceQuery(TestSerializer.java:38)
    at test.fwk.util.core.BaseTestSuiteCore.run(BaseTestSuiteCore.java:304)
     at test.fwk.util.core.BaseTestSuiteConf.run(BaseTestSuiteConf.java:186)
    at test.fwk.lispring.BaseTestSuite.run(BaseTestSuite.java:232)
    at test.fwk.lispring.BaseTestSuite.callAppropriateRun(BaseTestSuite.java:265)
    at test.fwk.util.core.BaseTestSuiteCore.run(BaseTestSuiteCore.java:199)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid embedded descriptor for "com/linkedin/history/api/protobuf/HistoryService.proto".
     at com.google.protobuf.Descriptors$FileDescriptor.internalBuildGeneratedFileFrom(Descriptors.java:268)
     at com.linkedin.history.api.protobuf.HistoryServiceProtos.(HistoryServiceProtos.java:1794)
Caused by: com.google.protobuf.Descriptors$DescriptorValidationException: com/linkedin/history/api/protobuf/HistoryService.proto: Dependencies passed to FileDescriptor.buildFrom() don't match those listed in the FileDescriptorProto.
     at com.google.protobuf.Descriptors$FileDescriptor.buildFrom(Descriptors.java:221)
     at com.google.protobuf.Descriptors$FileDescriptor.internalBuildGeneratedFileFrom(Descriptors.java:266)
```

I've read the post [here](http://groups.google.com/group/protobuf/browse_thread/thread/c0bd926a8f5ba6f5/a03ac6747e07c494?lnk=raot) but I think I'm doing everything correctly. Any suggestions on why I'm having the initializer errors? I'm compiling everything with the same -I flag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I *suspect* that the problem is that when you're finding the proto file, you've given it the full path, e.g. proto/com/foo/api/Service.proto but when it refers to it via the include directory, it's using com/foo/api/Service.proto

Simple fix - run this from the `proto` directory:

```
find . -name *.proto -exec protoc --java_out=../java -I=. {} \;
```

I must admit I can't remember a lot of the details of `protoc` (which I really should) but I suspect that will work.

Another alternative which *may* work:

```
protoc --java_out=java `find . -name '*.proto'`
```

i.e. pass all the proto files into a single call to protoc.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you're right, but I'm still having trouble after your suggestions. My imports do look like `com/foo/shared/Shared.proto`  

I'm now trying to pass the path ala `protoc --java_out=module/protobuf-api/java -I=module/protobuf-api/proto module/protobuf-api/proto/com/foo/api/Service.proto`. I think this *should* work since the imports are now relative from the path given with -I. I'd prefer not to import the whole path from the project root, just a relative path from some base package so I can more easily integrate it with our build system.
  I'll keep trying. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Joshua: If you could come up with a short but complete example which shows this, it would be really helpful. Apart from anything else, I'd like to check how it fares with my C# port :)

Comment: Actually, our test framework must be doing something very odd. When I invoke the test from the command line with org.junit.runner.JUnitCore, everything works fine. For some reason the FileDescriptor doesn't have the fully qualified name when run with our Framework. I'll report more if I can find anything useful for others. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error type in C# and here was my problem: I called the `protoc` in a pre-build step in my project. There I used Visual Studio built-in macros like `$(SolutionDir)` and `$(ProjectDir)` to retrieve necessary paths. Since I referenced `*.proto` files from other projects, I used two `--proto_path` options: one for the root path (to resolve `import` paths) and one for the file itself. My solution file was inside a subdirectory of the root directory, so I used the relative path `..` to get to the root. Proto files are always in subdirectory `gen` of the particular project. All in all, the command was like this:

```
protoc.exe --proto_path=$(SolutionDir).. --proto_path=$(ProjectDir)gen  $(ProjectDir)gen\DemoFile.proto
```

It compiled fine, but I got the `System.TypeInitializationException` at runtime on calling `CreateBuilder()` method. The problem was that both paths `$(SolutionDir)..` and `$(ProjectDir)` (though effectively pointing to the same directory) had different textual representation due to the relative path component `..`. I solved the problem by consistently using the same path like this:

```
protoc.exe --proto_path=$(SolutionDir).. $(SolutionDir)..\My\Demo\Project\Directory\gen\DemoFile.proto
```

It cost me almost 3 days to narrow down and recognize the problem, so I share my solution here in hope that it will save some time for someone.